# Dynamic allocation leaks memory?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
bool CPythonNonPlayer::LoadNonPlayerData(const char *c_szFileName)
{
    DWORD dwElements;

    TMobTable *pTable = (TMobTable *) zObj.GetBuffer();

    for(DWORD i = 0; i < dwElements; ++i, ++pTable)
    {
        TMobTable *pNonPlayerData = new TMobTable;
        memcpy(pNonPlayerData, pTable, sizeof(TMobTable));
        m_NonPlayerDataMap.insert(TNonPlayerDataMap::value_type(pNonPlayerData->dwVnum, pNonPlayerData));
    }

    return true;
}
```

My question is: what am I doing wrong? This leaks a lot of memory. After each call of this function, the application usage increases by 10MB.

Comment: Any time you have a `new` you need a `delete`. I do not see you using `delete`.

Comment: Don't try to use `new` and `delete` yourself. This will prevent you from much trouble and grief.

Comment: This code will leak memory if `map::insert` fails.  Never write code like this if you're going to use a `map` to store a pointer to dynamic memory in a map, and just assume that the `map.insert` is going to work.  If the key value in the map already exists, then you have a leak.

Comment: `TMobTable` must be hilariously large.

Comment: Where is `dwElements` initialized?

Comment: Short answer: Don't use `new` unless you've ruled out pretty much every other possibility. Here, it's entirely gratuitous.

Comment: Don't vandalize your own question. That is not permitted.

Comment: Again, don't vandalize your question. Continuing to do that may cause the mods to suspend you.

Comment: I just want to be delete and next time I will be very very carefully with my account

Comment: @marc The problem is that people have spent time answering, for now the only thing you can do is to flag your own post for moderator. Explain why you like to delete it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be vandalized.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in this function. The problem is in the way you handle `m_NonPlayerDataMap`. This function transfers ownership of some objects to that map, and it's that map's responsibility to `delete` them when it's done with them. I'll bet it doesn't.

By the way, to avoid this kind of problem *just don't do this*. Don't use `new` unless you really need to. Instead, make the map a map of *values* rather than a map of pointers. If you can't figure out any way to make that happen, at least use smart pointers rather than raw pointers.

Comment: It's worse than that.  If the `map::insert` fails due to the key already existing in the map, the leak is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Use smart pointer wrappers to handle memory management for you, eg:

If using a version earlier than C++11:

```
#include <memory>

// std::auto_ptr is not container-safe!
typedef std::map<DWORD, TMobTable*> TNonPlayerDataMap;
TNonPlayerDataMap m_NonPlayerDataMap;

...

bool CPythonNonPlayer::LoadNonPlayerData(const char *c_szFileName)
{
    DWORD dwElements = ...;
    ...

    // I'm assuming this just returns a pointer to an existing memory
    // buffer and is not actually allocating a new buffer.  If it is,
    // you need to free it when you are done copying it...
    //
    TMobTable *pTable = (TMobTable *) zObj.GetBuffer();

    for(DWORD i = 0; i < dwElements; ++i, ++pTable)
    {
        std::auto_ptr<TMobTable> pNonPlayerData(new TMobTable);

        // don't use memcpy! better would be to give TMobTable a copy constructor instead...
        // std::auto_ptr<TMobTable> pNonPlayerData(new TMobTable(*pTable));
        //
        *pNonPlayerData = *pTable;

        // if successful, release local ownership of the object.
        // if failed, ownership will remain here and free the object when the auto_ptr goes out of scope.
        //
        if (m_NonPlayerDataMap.insert(std::make_pair(pNonPlayerData->dwVnum, pNonPlayerData.get())).second)
            pNonPlayerData.release();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using C++11 or later:

```
#include <memory>

// std::unique_ptr is container-safe!
typedef std::map<DWORD, std::unique_ptr<TMobTable>> TNonPlayerDataMap;
TNonPlayerDataMap m_NonPlayerDataMap;

...

bool CPythonNonPlayer::LoadNonPlayerData(const char *c_szFileName)
{
    DWORD dwElements = ...;
    ...

    // I'm assuming this just returns a pointer to an existing memory
    // buffer and is not actually allocating a new buffer.  If it is,
    // you need to free it when you are done copying it...
    //
    TMobTable *pTable = (TMobTable *) zObj.GetBuffer();

    for(DWORD i = 0; i < dwElements; ++i, ++pTable)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<TMobTable> pNonPlayerData(new TMobTable);
        //
        // or, if using C++14 or later:
        // std::unique_ptr<TMobTable> pNonPlayerData = std::make_unique<TMobTable>();

        // don't use memcpy! better would be to give TMobTable a copy constructor instead...
        // std::unique_ptr<TMobTable> pNonPlayerData(new TMobTable(*pTable));
        // std::unique_ptr<TMobTable> pNonPlayerData = std::make_unique<TMobTable>(*pTable);
        //
        *pNonPlayerData = *pTable;

        // if successful, ownership of the object is transferred into the map.
        // if failed, ownership will remain here and free the object when the unique_ptr goes out of scope.
        //
        m_NonPlayerDataMap.insert(std::make_pair(pNonPlayerData->dwVnum, std::move(pNonPlayerData)));
    }

    return true;
}
```